# How can I get virtual, shared, resident memory for a process on Windows XP 32 bit on the command line?

Tags: windows-xp, memory

How can I retrieve detailed memory information (virtual, shared, resident) from the command line for a specific process? `tasklist` just gives a "memory usage", which as far as I've been told, it's RSS+Shared.

Comment: Can you try to use `pmon` from windows server 2003 resource kit (compatible with XP) http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657 ?

Answer (score 3):

[`PSList`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682.aspx) from Microsoft/Sysinternals should get you most of the way there:

> **Memory Abbreviation Key**
>
> All memory values are displayed in KB.
>
> - Pri: Priority
> - Thd: Number of Threads
> - Hnd: Number of Handles
> - VM: Virtual Memory
> - WS: Working Set
> - Priv: Private Virtual Memory
> - Priv Pk: Private Virtual Memory Peak
> - Faults: Page Faults
> - NonP: Non-Paged Pool
> - Page: Paged Pool
> - Cswtch: Context Switches

Also perhaps check out PowerShell's [`Get-Process`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176855.aspx).

Comment: All Sysinternals Troubleshooting Utilities(i.e. PSList) have been rolled up into a single program called [Sysinternals Suite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062).